# Two javascript alert windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm currently using the following code for a disclaimer message when the user clicks a link to an external source;

```
$(
    function () {
    $("a[href^='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"']), [href^='https://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"'])")
        .attr("target","_blank")
        .click(function(e) {
            alert('My message here');
        });
    });
```

Which works, but I need to add a second message for when a specific link is click. I've tried adding some if and else if statements (example below), but this doesn't work. Am I using the right method with else if or should I try a different route?

```
$(
function () {


$(if "a[href^='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"']), [href^='https://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"'])")
    .attr("target","_blank")
    .click (function(e) {
        alert('My original message here');
       });
  (else if
  "a[href^='http://theurlhere'")
    .attr("target","_blank")
    .click (function(e) {
        alert('Test');
        });
    });
```

Comment: `(else if` ? This is random. Please have a look at some documentation.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have 2 alerts at the same time. JavaScript executes all code in single thread and once alert is shown script execution won't continue untill you hit 'ok'.

The only way you can have 2 alerts is implement them yourself for example with bootstrap [alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) or [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (or even both).

You may also want to complete interactive tutorials [here](http://try.jquery.com/) to undestand jquery selectors

**Update:**

Here is an example code for 2 modal alerts using bootstrap and jquery. It's displaying 2 alerts inside bootstrap modal.

**Html**

```
<div id='modal' class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id='alert1' class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none">Second alert will be shown in 3 seconds</div>
      <div id='alert2' class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="display:none">Second alert</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick='showAlerts()'>Show 2 Alerts</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showAlerts() {
  showAlert("alert1");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showAlert('alert2')
  }, 3000);
}

function showAlert(alertId) {
  $('#' + alertId).show();
  $('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uyajDh8MxNnUyEF7bZHb?p=preview) is working plunker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the interactive tutorials link. I'd not thought about a modal box as an option, this would work better than a simple alert window.

Comment: @hoops78 You might want to have a look at the example in original answer

Comment: Thank you. I've had a look and I think I should be able to tweak this as I need the different alerts depending on which link is clicked, rather than alert 2 after alert 1.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors have to be separated:

```
$(function()
{
    $("a[href^='http://']:not([href*='" + location.hostname + "']), href^='https://']:not([href*='" + location.hostname + "'])")
    .attr("target", "_blank")
    .click(function(e)
    {
        alert('My original message here');
    });

    $("a[href^='http://theurlhere'")
    .attr("target", "_blank")
    .click(function(e)
    {
        alert('Test');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the above and it brings up the original alert 5 times rather than the new one. I will do some more research and play around with this.

Comment: @hoops78 you can provide full example, including HTML code, using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). That I will be able to update answer to fix issues.

Comment: Most of the site is within a CMS, so I've created a fiddle with the menu part [link](http://jsfiddle.net/04adydj2/)

Comment: @hoops78 so problem is that for second link both `alert('Message 1');` and `alert('Message 2');` are shown? While you want only `alert('Message 1');` to be shown?

Comment: Message 1 is for all external links, but then I need just message 2 for the specified link

Comment: @hoops78 take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04adydj2/1/). Is it the desired behaviour?